# Date Navigation resets the vertical scroll to the top

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Clicking the Previous, Next or Refresh button always resets the vertical scroll to the top of the resource list.  Is there a way to preserve the vertical scroll position during refetch events?

Comment: Not in this demo it doesn't: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler . If you have a specific issue with your code, we'll need to see it. Are you perhaps re-fetching your resources at the same time, or something? Without code and some more detail, we can only speculate.

Comment: I was automatically fetching resources on navigate.  I set fetchResourcesOnNavigate to false and implemented my own resources object that sends the date parameters I choose, and when I choose.